# x% OFF tag in product listings, home and details page

Tags: cart, template, catalog-price-rules

I would like to add a x% OFF tag in products in home, listings, and product page, except for certain SKUs and categories.

This would be easily done by a catalog price rule.

My problem is that this only applies to banktransfer payment methods.

This suggests a shopping cart rule. Now this is a problem, when I try to validate the rule for listed products which aren't in shop cart.

If to go the catalog rule solution instead, I'm not certain about the layout, since I tested this and it showed a price like "old-price" with strike. I don't want to mirror the behavior of "special-price" layout here.

What would you suggest ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Well, it's done, and I learned a couple of things: (...)

## Edit

It was a tough day.

Catalog price rules, in the end of the day, are indeed applied to the shopping cart.

It started with our catalog price rule (which conditions were an exact duplicate of a  shopping cart rule) strangely "not working" only for the product detail page. To fix it, we re-applied the catalog rule after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332955/magento-catalog-price-discount-rules-not-apply-in-product-detail-page/12671235#12671235).

Then the rule was applied over all our site, doubling the discount first in catalog then in cart, and we had to work quick to fix this.

### bottom line:

We deactivated the catalog price rule, reapplied to clean it from prices, then in `price.phtml` we did something like this:

```
/* Flag catalog rule % discount */
/* Rule with id=2 is the catalog price rule, deactivated and only loaded here */
if (!Mage::registry('AtSightDiscountRuleConditions')) {
    Mage::register('AtSightDiscountRuleConditions', Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(2)->getConditions());
}
$flagAtSightDiscount = Mage::registry('AtSightDiscountRuleConditions')->validate($_product) ? 1 : 0;
```

Finally, we output `$flagAtSightDiscount` in product price tag attribute, and kept our jQuerying for DOM manipulation in those elements.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. How did you manage to apply discount only for a particular payment method? Is that in your shopping cart rule?

Comment: Yes. There is a condition for payment method that is present only in shopping cart rules. I copied the other conditions from the catalog price rule.